# Faint border appears on mobile devices on borders of divs etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

When I code in HTML the design works fine on Desktop screens but when viewed on tablets/phones I get a very faint grey line on the border of any  etc.

I have attached an image to illustrate the problem...(I'm referring to the horizontal grey line on the top of the tab and not the two vertical ones).

[image: Mysterious horizontal line on mobile devices]

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see your HTML/CSS to find the problem. It sounds like a media query issue.